# TextBox edition does not end when hitting return/enter key

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, textbox

I have added a text box to my page and when I tap on it the keyboard shows up and I can edit its content, but when I tap ENTER/RETURN button on the keyboard the edition does not stop. How to end it?

Comment: I assume you are using ASP.NET?

Comment: That's right. No java of any kind ; )

Comment: That functionality happens on the browser. It has to be JS unless you plan to post back to the server on the every single key press.

Comment: This is tagged "windows-phone-7", why are we talking javascript and ASP.Net???

Comment: Sorry. Deleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to `KeyUp` event of the `TextBox` and Focus some other control if the Key that was pressed is Key.Enter.